# How can I get non-escaped utf-8 output from Django tests?

Tags: django-testing, utf8-decode, python-unicode

Using Django 1.3 with python 2.7, a testcase like:

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function, division
from django.test import TestCase

class SetContextWordsTests(TestCase):
    def test_utf8_output(self):
    msg = "你好"
    self.fail(msg)
```

Gives me the output:

```
AssertionError: \u4f60\u597d
```

I'd like to see:

```
AssertionError: 你好
```

The terminal supports utf-8, and utf-8 is printed unescaped everywhere else, only escaping the output from tests.

- I've tried doing self.fail(msg.encode('utf-8')) but that results in a
  UnicodeDecodeError.
- I've tried setting DEFAULT_CHARSET and TESTING_CHARSET, but they don't have an effect.

What do I need to change to get this output?